# how do invalid username or password warning bypass on selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I want do bypass for "invalid login or password" warning info. Because if this info coming more 7-8 times, this site's servers ask me an robot verification. How can i check my passwords just by trying quickly?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

#Selenium Settings
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

#Checker PhelipeSX
def Checker(username, password):
    try:
        time.sleep(4.4)
        driver.get("https://fullhdfilmizle.pw/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Ffullhdfilmizle.pw%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1") #Load the website
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emailField"]').send_keys(username) #Put the username/email
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(password) #Put the password
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"]').click() #Click on Login
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rester_connecte_1"]').click() #Click on Login

            access = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div/ul[2]/li[2]/form/button').text #Copy the text, to see if the login informations are goods.

        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Error, can't find elements")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error, can't access to the website.") #Print error, if cant access to the website

#Username and password checker
Checker("myusername", "123456")
Checker("myusername", "1234567")
```

Comment: Is this a BruteForce attempt to hack minecraft accounts? take care

Comment: yes it can be used for this purpose. I just want to learn, i'm not a malicious